# Installing deadbeef

Tags: software-installation

I am very new to Ubuntu. I am trying to install deadbeef but it *apparently* installs but then I can't find the allegedly-installed app. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Up to date packages are available via some third party packages, so installing the software on Ubuntu is easy. Just add the PPA to your system, update the local repository index and install the deadbeef package. So to install deedbeef, open the terminal and run the following commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:starws-box/deadbeef-player

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install deadbeef
```