# Deadbeef player doesn't access my storage hdd

Tags: music, rhythmbox, filemanager, mp3, deadbeef

I've installed both `deadbeef` and `foobar2000` and neither one lists my storage HDD other than the main OS SSD.

`Rhythmbox` lists all HDDs and I can drag & drop music files with QMMP.
And I'm trying to set `deadbeef` as the primary music player.

How can I do that?

Comment: Where is your "storage hdd" mounted? How is it mounted? `deadbeef` is not a Ubuntu package. Ask at http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/ - they have a "bug tracker"

Comment: How did you installed `deadbeef`? Please add output of `which deadbeef` and `snap list deadbeef-vs` to the question.

Comment: I installed deadbeef-vs as a snap package and the hdd is attached via sata with an optical drive caddy to my laptop. . 

From lsblk command, 

[CODE] sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465.8G  0 part /media/louie/Storage HDD [/CODE]

Comment: If you really like DeadBeef, you can install it [from `ppa:starws-box/deadbeef-player` PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/972839/66509).

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of the question linked above. This issue, unlike the one described in the linked question, has nothing to do with removable media. I am facing the same issue and, just like the OP, I have no removable media attached to my machine.

Comment: Anyways, I followed @N0rbert advice and installed the player from starws-box; instructions here: https://launchpad.net/~starws-box/+archive/ubuntu/deadbeef-player